# In Gitllab, why do I sometimes need to manually apply to aply a Merge Request and sometimes I just have to click merge?

Tags: gitlab

for some of my gitlab repos I just need to click merge  and it automatically merges and applies my chnages but for other of my repos I have to merge and then press the manual apply button.
Does anyone know whey this is..I've been Googlimng but without much success
any help gratefully received

Comment: Can you add some screenshots to your question?